# Tarpc how to call outer struct's method?

Tags: rust, rpc

I'm using [tarpc](https://github.com/google/tarpc) to create a tcp service.

##### rpc service:

```
#[tarpc::service]
pub trait Hello {
    async fn say_hi() -> String;
}
```

#### server:

```
pub struct HelloServer;

#[tarpc::server]
impl Hello for HelloServer {
   /// requires to call SingletonInstance::say_hi()
   async fn say_hi(self, context: tarpc::context::Context) ->String {
      return "hi".to_string();
     }
 }

/// I want HelloServer to be a proxy of SingletonInstance
/// The data flow like this:
/// client tarpc call -> helloServer.say_hi -> singletonInstance.say_hi -> send response through tarpc
/// 
pub struct SingletonInstance {}

impl SingletonInstance {
    pub async fn say_hi() -> String {
        return String::new()
    }
}
```

**Full Example** https://github.com/divflex/demo-rpc

**Question:**
The `HelloServer` is basiclly a proxy for the `SingletonInstance`,so the `say_hi` method need to call the same method on `SingletonInstance`.
What's the proper way to call `SingletonInstance::say_hi` ?

**My idea:**
I created a `tx`(`tokio::sync::mpsc`) property on `HelloServer`, so the instance can use `self.tx.send()` to communicate with `SingletonInstance`.But HelloServer also need a receiver to get results. This seems too complicated.

Comment: Please only ask one question per Stack Overflow question and please include a [mre] as formatted text **within** the question, a link may be a good further reed but the question *has to be* self contained.

Comment: @cafce25 Ok , I will modify my question soon. sorry

Comment: What is the problem with `SingletonInstance::say_hi()`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I need to access `SingletonInstance`'s api from other app. It is an rust binding for c++ lib, so it's hard to be used directly with Tarpc. For example, it  cannot be cloned which tarpc server requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to call `SingletonInstance::say_hi` from `HelloServer` is to add a link/reference to `SingletonInstance` in `HelloServer`. You can do this by adding a field to the `HelloServer` struct that holds an `Arc<SingletonInstance>` and then use this reference to call the `say_hi` method on the `SingletonInstance`:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

pub struct HelloServer {
    singleton: Arc<SingletonInstance>,
}

#[tarpc::server]
impl Hello for HelloServer {
    async fn say_hi(self, context: tarpc::context::Context) -> String {
        self.singleton.say_hi().await
    }
}

pub struct SingletonInstance {}

impl SingletonInstance {
    pub async fn say_hi(&self) -> String {
        "hi".to_string()
    }
}
```

This way, you can avoid using channels to communicate between `HelloServer` and `SingletonInstance`.

Another way is you create an instance of `SingletonInstance` onto `HelloServer` (but that's not what SingletonInstance means :)

```rust
use tarpc::context;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct HelloServer {
    instance: SingletonInstance,
}

#[tarpc::server]
impl Hello for HelloServer {
    async fn say_hi(self, _: context::Context) -> String {
        self.instance.say_hi().await
    }
}

pub struct SingletonInstance {}

impl SingletonInstance {
    pub async fn say_hi(&self) -> String {
        "hi".to_string()
    }
}
```

Cloning is necessary because tarpc creates a new instance of the server for each connection, and we need to be able to clone the server to serve multiple clients.

Comment: thanks. the first one is good . the second is not an option.